# How to get item position in a listview through matching string android

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview with custom adapter, and I have a edittext for input search. What I want to achieve is to get the item position from a listview that matches with the string from the edittext.

All the examples on the web shows how to get the item position of a listview onclick event. But I can't figure it out how to do this my given query above. Any input is appreciated very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the text as content description to the view. Use `findViewsWithText(constraintString)`. Make sure other views do not have same content description because ListView will only bind data to existing views, which previously might have holded this content description and you would end up getting incorrect view ref.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you need, take a look at the `AutoCompleteTextView` [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/text.html#AutoComplete).

This will display a mini list, below the EditText box, of strings that match what the user is typing. The user will then be able to select the item from the AutoComplete list which will invoke a method that passes you all kinds of info on the list item itself.

This all assumes that you are using a `List<String>`, `ArrayList<>`, or some other string `Collection`.

Sorry if I didnt help, give us more info on what exactly you need it to do.